# About the view controllers in iOS Photos app

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I want to study iOS Swift programming by cloning Photos App on iPhone.

It seems that its root view controller should be an UITabBarController, which contains 4 view controllers: Library, For You, Albums, and Search.

Let's first study the Library:

[image]

In the above screenshot A,B and C: After clicking the select button in A, B is displayed; And after clicking an image grid in A, C is displayed.

My question is: Should the A,B,C screens be implemented with one view controller, or should they be implemented with 3 view controllers separately?

I may be a novice on this question, but I hope someone could give me advice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

for you and as any developer starts learning, use 3 views for now and after a while you can enhance it by using the same view but with different 3 custom cells. That's for the **app over all** but for **library** only two views are enough for it, one for viewing images and select them and the second one for the selected one